# Is "I will defend it" in Barenaked Ladies' Navigate a reference?

Tags: lyrics

In the Barenaked Ladies song "[Navigate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmYySE3a-ps)", there's a line:

> It's home and I will defend it

To me the "I will defend it" seems slightly out of place with the tone of the rest of the song, which is using wilderness exploration in a somewhat metaphorical sense.

I get the strong impression that the phrase is supposed to be a reference. I initially thought that it might be a quote to a "patriotic" song they're explicitly making a callback to. Barenaked Ladies is (proudly) a Canadian band, so I imagine it would be a Canadian anthem they're referencing, and the meaning of the referenced song dovetails with the "pride in the rugged Canadian wilderness" aesthetic the rest of the song is going for. However I didn't see anything in the lyrics of "*O, Canada*" which might fit. I'm also not up to speed enough on my Canadiana to know if there's another work it might be instead.

Is this line a reference/quote/callback to a different song (or poem/other work), and if so, which one?